# How to check if an instance of NSMutableArray is null or not

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

How to check an `NSMutableArray` is null or not ?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If you want to check if it is empty:

```
if ([myMutableArray count] == 0) { ... }
```

If you want to check if the variable is `nil`:

```
if (!myMutableArray) { ... }
```

or:

```
if (myMutableArray == nil) { ... }
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for the good answer, I also noticed that `If([myMutableArray count] > 0)` will return false if nil or zero records in the array, meaning that il arrays act as a empty array (when count is used). :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//if the array has a count of elements greater than 0, then the array contains elements
if(myarray.count>0){
    NSlog(@"myarray contains values/elements");
}
else{ //else the array has no elements
    NSlog(@"myarray is nil");
}
```

Comment: If `myarray` is empty, but not nil, then it would still fall into the `else` branch.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to check it.

1. ```
   if (array == [NSNull null])
   {
       //myarray is blank
   }
   ```
2. ```
   if(array.count==0)
   {
       //myarray is blank
   }
   ```
3. ```
   if(array == nil)
   {
       //my array is blank
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this way also...

```
if self.yourMutableArray.count == 0 {
     // Your Mutable array is empty. 
} else {
    // Your Mutable array is not empty.
}
```