# How do I identify NSDictionary is empty or not

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need help.

I want to show data if there is data in dictionary else I want to show No-Data screen if there is no value in dictionary. But problem is like this that I'm getting count as 1. Though there is no value in dictionary.

As you all are trying to guess this one is duplicate. But my question is little-bit different. In this dictionary I have multiple key-value pairs. So I can't find for one key, that's why I'm just trying to get count of it's.

```
 NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)dict.count); //<-- It prints : 1

 NSLog(@"%@", dict); //<----It will print below structure with no data

//Output :- 
    (
            {
        }
    )
```

So how do I will identify like this dictionary to show it is empty. Though I tried but it is going count as 1.

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745336/check-if-nsdictionary-is-empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if NSDictionary is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745336/check-if-nsdictionary-is-empty)

Comment: Hi I have edited my question. So plz can you give me solution for my question. I need help.

Comment: Are you sure `dict` is a dictionary? According to the output the object seems to be an **array** containing one empty dictionary.

Comment: sorry its nsmutablearray

Comment: can give solution for this

Comment: Then a count of `1` is correct.

Comment: ok but if there is single data then what will be count???

Comment: If this is an array then please follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2048068/5167909

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the output `dict` is not a dictionary (`{}`), it's an array (`()`) containing one empty dictionary.

To check if there is a dictionary in the array which is not empty you could use (I renamed `dict` to `array`)

```
if (array.count > 0 && array[0].count > 0) { // will be evaluated to true if the dictionary is not empty
```

Comment: Property 'count' not found on object of type 'id' -> array[0]

Comment: NSMutableArray *dict = self.product.productAllergenInformationModuleArray; // Assigning NSDictionary to it.

Comment: Declare the array `NSMutableArray<NSDictionary *> *array = ` and please don't name it `dict`

Comment: if (array.count > 0 && [array[0] count] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Null");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"%@", array);
    }

Comment: I've tried this way, as you told. But still it prints empty array instead of Null

Comment: Please **read** the code and try to understand it. The `if` block is printed if the array is **not** empty (`> 0`) and the `else` block if it's empty. Or check `if (array.count > 0 && array[0].count == 0) {`